# Getting the prototype of a constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypal-inheritance

I was reading about the `new` keyword in javascript on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype#description) and came across this line:

> When a function is called with new, the constructor's prototype property will become the resulting object's prototype.

However, the code below didn't behave as I would expect. I assumed that `Car.prototype` would return the Car's prototype object. But it seems to just return an empty object. What am I missing here?

```
function Car(make, model, year) {
  this.make = make,
  this.model = model,
  this.year = year,
  this.started = false,
  this.start = function () {
     this.started = true;
  }),
  this.stop = function () {
      this.started = false;
  });
}
let corolla = new Car("Toyota", "Corolla", 2016);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(corolla)); //{}
console.log(Car.prototype); //{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are absolutely correct. However, the prototype *is* an empty object because you never assign any properties to it. (instead, you assign properties to the newly created object itself.)

Instead of assigning to `this.start` and `this.stop` from within the constructor function body, you'd have to assign to `Car.prototype.start` and `Car.prototype.stop` outside of the constructor function (below).

```js
function Car(make, model, year) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
  this.started = false;
}
Car.prototype.start = function () {
   this.started = true;
};
Car.prototype.stop = function () {
    this.started = false;
};

let corolla = new Car("Toyota", "Corolla", 2016);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(corolla));
console.log(Car.prototype);
```

Comment: The generalised mentions with `if` and `for` are not entirely correct. Given single-lined code without blocks.

Comment: @JavaScript In these cases, the single statement which constitutes the body of the `if`/`for` statement is terminated with `;` and not the `if` statement itself. The syntax of `if` (without `else`, for simplicity) is `if (<expresion>) <statement>`. The statement now may be a single statement with syntax `<statement content>[;]` (the optional `;` is part of the statement) or a block statement with syntax `{ <statement1> <statement2> ... <statementN> }`.